# On which closed Riemannian manifolds are geodesics always recurrent?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $M$ be a closed Riemannian manifold. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $M$ to ensure that for every point $p \in M$, and every geodesic $\gamma: [0, \infty) \to M$ with $\gamma(0) = p$, we have that $\liminf_{t \to \infty} d(\gamma(t), p) = 0$?

*Note: Here d denotes the usual Riemannian distance.*

Comment: A theorem of Anosov shows that  the geodesic  flow  on the unit sphere bundle of a compact manifold with negative curvature is ergodic.   so for most $p$, the geodesic that started at $p$ will return infinitely often to any neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu that's definitely an answer... unless the OP really wants both _necessary_ and _sufficient_, in which case I can't really see any way to formulate a simple answer that includes both Anosov's theorem and Zoll manifolds.

Comment: Hm, are there sufficient conditions for it to hold for *all* p? I am aware that ergodicity of the geodesic flow gets us topological recurrence (the definition involving $\liminf$ I gave) almost everywhere on the geodesic flow, hence on the manifold itself - but I don’t know how to ensure recurrence pointwise everywhere.

Comment: I wasn't finished with my coffee when I wrote the comment. The geodesic flow  on any compact Riemann manifold is volume preserving and the Poincare recurrence theorem  shows that any trajectory of the flow will intersect any open set infinitely often.

Comment: Hm, from what I understand the Poincare recurrence theorem ensures recurrence for the trajectory of almost every point. Does this easily extend to every point?

Comment: Certainly geodesic flows on manifolds of negative curvature have *some* points that are not recurrent.

Comment: A closes manifold always has periodic geodesics. Isn’t it enough to answer the question ?

Comment: Not really, since it isn’t guaranteed that all geodesics will be periodic.

Comment: I could be wrong in this, but it seems to me that I read ages ago and in Russian (that's how unsure I am of what I'm saying ...) a paper by Nadirashvili where he proves that such a Riemannian metric on the 2-torus must be flat by reducing the result to Hopf's characterization of flat tori.  I don't have access to MathScinet at the moment, but if you do you can easily check.

Comment: What are known examples of such manifolds, beyond flat tori? Is there a single other example?

Comment: Does a sphere not satisfy this? @YCor

Comment: Ah yes, now I even remember there's a whole book about closed Riemannian manifolds in which every geodesic is closed, so it looks like a broadening of this class. And sure, it includes round spheres.

Answer (score 5):

This is a comment that is meant to show that one should not look for such Riemannian manifolds among negatively curved ones. Indeed, let $\Sigma$ be a compact surface with a metric of negative curvature. Then for any point $p$ there is a geodesic $\gamma: [0,\infty)$ such that $\lim \inf_{t\to \infty}(p,\gamma(t))>0$.

*Proof.* Take any simple closed geodesic $\eta$ on $\Sigma$ that doesn't contain $p$. Parametrise $\eta$ by $S^1=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$.  Consider a geodesic segment $\gamma_s$ that joins $p$ with a point $\eta(s)$ and let $s\to \infty$. You will be able to vary $\gamma_s$ continuously changing $s$ continuously (because curvature is negative). Then segments $\gamma_s$ will converge in the limit to a geodesic ray that accumulates to $\eta$.

This construction generalises to any dimension.

One might wonder about positive curvature. Of course, if we take a round sphere, this is a good example, all trajectories are periodic. However, I am not quite sure if a generic $2$-sphere of positive curvature has the property you are asking for. Here a toy model are billiards (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards) in convex domains in $\mathbb R^2$.  This is a heavily studied subject. However, if one takes the second simplest billiard - an ellipse, then the property you are looking for doesn't hold for a subset of trajectories of codimension $1$. Namely, if you take a trajectory that passes through a focus and continue it to infinity, it will converge to the large axes of the ellipse. For all other trajectories, that don't pass through a focus indeed, there is recurrence - they come back to $p$ as close as you want.

Comment: How can $s$ go to infinity in $S^1$?

Comment: $S^1=\mathbb  R/\mathbb Z$ you go to infinity in $\mathbb R$. So $\gamma_s\ne \gamma_{s+1}$. For example if $\Sigma=\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2=T^2$, $p=(0,0)$ and the geodesic is the vertical circle $x_1=1/2$, then in the limit this construction will give you a vertical geodesic in through $(0,0)$

Comment: OK - so you are saying the following. Take a closed geodesic not passing through $p$, then any geodesic ray asymptotic to it (which can be chosen to be issued from $p$) has the required property. I agree. It is actually best seen by looking at the universal covering space. Still, it is a bit misleading to say that $s\in S^1$ goes to infinity in $\mathbb R$ :)

Comment: You are right, I was sloppy. To spell out this procedure one should indeed better go to the universal cover.

Comment: @Dmitri Panov Sorry for the late question, but I was wondering - is it possible to consider a billiard as a closed manifold? One can do the unfolding procedure, but this would make it unbounded. And of course when it’s not unfolded you have a boundary so it wouldn’t be closed.

Comment: The connection is as follows. Suppose you what to study the billiard $ax^2+by^2=1$. Then you consider the geodesic flow on the ellipsoid $ax^2+by^2+\varepsilon z^2=1$ and let $\varepsilon \to 0$. Then the geodesic flow "converges" to the billiard, this a classical idea. By the way, the geodesic flow on ellipsoids is very well understood. It is worth checking if such accumulating trajectories always exist (I forgot, but suspect they do). I guess the moral of this billiard example is that on a positively curved surface an infinite geodesic can accumulate to a closed one (I believe it's true).

Answer (score 3):

Just so that it doesn't get lost in the comments: in this paper Nadirashvili shows that a a $C^2$ Riemannian metric in the 2-torus for which the geodesic flow is recurrent (all points are Poisson stable) must be flat.

N. S. Nadirashvili, “Conditions of stability in the sense of Poisson of a geodesic flow on a torus”, Mat. Zametki, 44:1 (1988),  147–149